# How to view the GUI code in .form in intellij?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

Where is all the code that defines the layout of the GUI? I know IntelliJ keeps it in that .form file, but how do you get the java code of it?﻿

Comment: @Zephyr The question is perfectly clear for someone who's familiar with the technology being asked about (IntelliJ IDEA and its UI designer).

Comment: I've used IntelliJ for years. I do not know it's UI Designer, however. Perhaps it's a Swing thing and the question should be tagged as such?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the source code being generated, you can go to Settings | Editor | GUI Designer and select the option to generate .form files to source code. Note that generation to binary .class files (which is used by default) is more efficient and works in exactly the same way.

Comment: i think in new intellij the option is disabled... ?